# Measurable set - A sequence of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, M, \mu)$ be a measure space, and $f_n:X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ sequence of measurable functions.

How can I show that the set of $x$ that for them $f_n(x)$ has a subsequence that converges to $0$ is a measurable set?

Comment: I guess you meant fn:X→R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there is a subsequence of $\left(f_n(x)\right)_n$ converging to $0$ if and only if $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\exists n\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\left\vert f_n(x)\right\vert<\frac{1}{k}$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
&\left\{x\in X:\left(f_n(x)\right)_n\text{ has a subsequence converging to }0\right\}\\
=&\left\{x\in X:\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\text{ s.t. }\left\vert f_n(x)\right\vert<\frac{1}{k}\right\}\\
=&\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left\{x\in X:\left\vert f_n(x)\right\vert<\frac{1}{k}\right\}
\end{align*}
Since $f$ is measurable, it is a countable union and intersection of measurable sets and thus measurable itself.